# Lagrange multipliers for matrix calculus problem

Tags: matrices, lagrange-multiplier

I have what is probably an elementary matrix calculus question.

Let $P$ be a linear operator and $||\cdot||$ be the ordinary unsquared vector norm.

Suppose one wants to minimize $||Px||$ subject to the trace of $P$ being a prime $p$, and $I \succeq P \succeq 0.$ How can one do this using Lagrangian multipliers? We know that the derivative of $||Px||$ is $(Px)/||Px||$, but how can we capture the other conditions?

Comment: pray, refresh my memory, what means $I \succeq P \succeq 0$?

Comment: I think I got it, correct me if I'm wrong, $A \succeq B$ means $A - B$ is positive semi-definite, right?